# How to join multiple Kafka Topics inside a .Net distributed application

Tags: .net, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka with .Net Core and I have 2 topics. In which both contain information from the same entity and are partitioned by the same key.

On my application, I´d like to `Join` both informations to process them together. This process is in-memory as it requires a reasonably low latency.

My application has multiple nodes running, so when one node spins up, It is assigned some partitions from the first topic `T1` (say `T1:P1`, `T1:P3`) and some partitions from the other topic `T2` (say `T2:P2`, `T2:P4`)

My issue is that I cant guarantee that a single application node will be assigned partitions of the same entity from both topics. It may be that a given entity ended up in `T1:P1` for the first topic and `T2:P3` on the second topic. In the example above I would not be able to mix them together.

I known that I can use a *consistent partitioner* on the producer side, so that at least I known that my entity ended up on the same partition number on both topics (e.g. `T1:P1`, `T2:P1`). It still doesn´t help me since I can be assigned any partition.

It seems that Kafka Streams would be suited for this scenario, however it still [doesn´t have an implementation for .net](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/344).

There are some possible solutions I thought of:

1. On the consumer, let kafka client assign partitions of `T1`, and in the callback of `PartitionsAssigned`, manually assign the same partitions on `T2`.
2. Make service stateless, and use a database. Save/retrieve the state upon each new message.
3. On my particular case, `T1` has a very high frequency and `T2` a lot less. I was thinking about reading ALL partitions from `T2` on every node (e.g. use a random groupId).

But all solutions present problems:

- On strategy (1), I am wary to loose messages of `T2` during a partition rebalance.
- Strategy (2) will introduce a latency, that I really didn´t want. Even if using redis for example it might become a problem.
- Solution (3) simply doens´t scale. I might be able to do it this time, but it will put some memory pressure on all my nodes.

Are there any other solutions I didn´t think of ?

Comment: You could use KSQL and .NET HTTP Client to invoke its REST API